# How to make dnf to install older versions of software

Tags: fedora, dnf

I need to install squid 3.1.23

When I run

```
 sudo dnf install squid-3.1.23
```

I get error

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:27:10 ago on Tue Jan 12 10:09:23 2016.
No package squid-3.1.23 available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

My architecture is `armv7l` and operating system is `Fedora release 22`

Comment: Why exactly that version? Newer versions fix bugs and iron out wrinkles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dnf` (or any other repository-based package installation tool), you can only install packages which are published in your repositories; `dnf install squid-3.1.23` instructs `dnf` to install version 3.1.23 of the `squid` package, which isn't available in the Fedora 22 repositories. (Fedora 22 currently has version 3.4.12.) To install version 3.1.23 you'd have to look for that version on https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/squid/. It seems the closest you'll get there is 3.1.19, but it's not built on `armv7l` anyway.

So I would suggest just building from source, if you really need that specific version.

Comment: An additional complication is that we don't keep updates on the mirrors forever, because they'd take too much space. So usually, the only versions available are the version built at release time plus the latest (and only the latest) update (if any).

Comment: We _do_ keep old builds around for at least three years (and so far, forever, but we don't promise that) even though they're gone from the mirror. The Packages link provided here is a great way to find them if you need 'em for some reason.

Comment: The Packages link is currently giving the message: `Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`